# Set theory reasoning that I don’t understand

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I’m currently reading How To Prove It by Velleman and I encounter a reasoning that I cannot understand.
Basically I would like to ask why the author set a function like this? Is that necessary to set a rule such that “i>n”? I mean, n is just the number of elements of set A so why we care about “something more than the elements of set A”?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etlYd.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOsr4.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: I never use this before but I will definitely try next time, thanks for your advance

Comment: The author is explaining how to define $f(i)$ for all $i\in\Bbb Z^+$, including in the case $i>n$.

Comment: Still confused…function g is already a bijection from function In to set A, and a0 is one of the elements of set A, so why the author define that “i>n, then f(i)=a0?” If i>n, isn’t that just means i is the “extra” elements of set In? (Since function g is bijection so that should not has such i )

Comment: In order for $f$ to have domain ${\mathbb Z}^{+},$ we need to know what $f(1)$ is, and what $f(2)$ is, and what $f(3)$ is, $\ldots,$ and what $f(n)$ is, and what $f(n+1)$ is, and what $f(n+2)$ is, $\ldots$ The use of $g$ only takes care of telling us what what $f(1)$ is, and what $f(2)$ is, and what $f(3)$ is, $\ldots,$ and what $f(n)$ is (but doesn't tell us anything about $f(n+1)$ or $f(n+2)$ or $\ldots).$

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Oh I see, but isn’t that mean every i “more” than n pairs with such one value called a0?

Comment: Alright, will do better next time

Comment: You can edit this question. Why not do better this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure what your question is so let me explain the proof as best I can.
The reason a rule is generated for $i>n$ is that we need to show an onto function from the set of all positive integers to the set $A$. For that reason you need to assign *some* value to the integers greater than $n$. For this you can just choose any number $a_0\in A$ and map every positive rational greater than $n$ to that element. This gives an onto function.